# Alinhamento radio com imagem

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, radiobutton

Estou tentando centralizar um item de radio - "bolinha" de seleção com uma imagem.

Porém já tentei diversos recursos usando *CSS* e não estou conseguindo.

Sabem qual recurso posso utilizar para conseguir este alinhamento?

```html
    <tr>
     <!-- #### BUG: Arrumar alinhamento entre a bolinha e a imagem. -->
     <td>Bandeira:</td>
     <td>
      <div class="celula-imagens">
       <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img src="img/visa-logo.png">
      </div> 
      <div class="celula-imagens">
       <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img src="img/mastercard-logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="celula-imagens">
       <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img src="img/american-express-logo.png">
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

[image: Radio com bandeiras]

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o estilo `vertical-align` nos `radios` e nas `imagens`:

```css
input[name='bandeira']{
   vertical-align: sub;
}

.celula-imagens img{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <!-- #### BUG: Arrumar alinhamento entre a bolinha e a imagem. -->
      <td>Bandeira:</td>
      <td>
         <div class="celula-imagens">
            <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img height="20" src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/visa-logo.png">
         </div> 
         <div class="celula-imagens">
            <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img height="40" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/MasterCard_Logo.svg/2000px-MasterCard_Logo.svg.png">
         </div>
         <div class="celula-imagens">
            <input type="radio" name="bandeira"><img height="40" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/American_Express_logo.svg/2000px-American_Express_logo.svg.png">
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da retrocompatibilidade que o seu projeto precisa atingir (até quais browsers antigos ele precisa dar suporte), você pode solucionar com `display: flex`. Você pode verificar quais browsers dão suporte no [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). (Obrigado Ricardo Pontual por sinalizar isso).

Aí é só aplicar esse código na sua folha de estilo que resolve:

```
.celula-imagens {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap
}

.celula-imagens input {
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center;
    align-self: center
}
```

Você define a div que seleciona esses elementos como `display: flex` e consegue manipular o alinhamento horizontal dos seus elementos

Comment: só uma observação que algumas versões não tão atuais dos navegadores podem não dar suporte ao `display: flex`

Comment: Opa, muito bem pontuado. Editei minha resposta para contemplar a retrocompatibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma opção com `transform:translateY` que pode te servir. Ela funciona inclusive no IE9 e em todos os Browsers modernos.

Não precisei mexer em nada no seu código, só acrescentei umas classes como vc pode ver abaixo. *Outro detalhe é que ele sempre vai alinhar na vertical independente do tamanho da imagem!*

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div > input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div > img{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <!-- #### BUG: Arrumar alinhamento entre a bolinha e a imagem. -->
        <td>Bandeira:</td>
        <td>
            <div class="celula-imagens">
                <input type="radio" name="bandeira">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/50/50">
            </div>
            <div class="celula-imagens">
                <input type="radio" name="bandeira">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/70/70">
            </div>
            <div class="celula-imagens">
                <input type="radio" name="bandeira">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```