# Problema para alinhamento

Tags: flutter, css

Eu estou com um problema, não consigo colocar o RadioListTile do lado de uma imagem, quando eu tento colocar ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem dar uma olhada no meu codigo e ver o que tem de errado:

```
Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage
(image: AssetImage("Imagens/Fundo login.jpg"),
fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
 ),
   child: Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
     children: <Widget>[

       Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 190, 20),
         child: Image.asset(
           "Imagens/Coreano.jpg",
           width: 500,
           height: 50,
         ),
       ),

      Center(
        child:  Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 0),
          child: RadioListTile(
              title: Text("Coreano"),
              activeColor: Color(0xff5CE6B8),
              value: "coreano",
              groupValue: _escolhaUsuario,
              onChanged: (String escolha){
                setState(() {
                  _escolhaUsuario = escolha;
                });
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),

       Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 190, 0),
         child: Image.asset(
           "Imagens/Espanhol.jpg",
           width: 500,
           height: 53,
         ),
       ),
           Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 0),
             child: RadioListTile(
                 title: Text("Espanhol"),
                 activeColor: Color(0xff5CE6B8),
                 value: "espanhol",
                 groupValue: _escolhaUsuario,
                 onChanged: (String escolha){
                   setState(() {
                     _escolhaUsuario = escolha;
                   });
                 }
             ),
           ),
       Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 190, 0),
         child: Image.asset(
           "Imagens/Ingles.jpg",
           width: 500,
           height: 43,
         ),
       ),
       Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 0),
         child: RadioListTile(
             title: Text("Ingles"),
             activeColor: Color(0xff5CE6B8),
             value: "ingles",
             groupValue: _escolhaUsuario,
             onChanged: (String escolha){
               setState(() {
                 _escolhaUsuario = escolha;
               });
             }
         ),
       ),
       Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
         child: RaisedButton(
             shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:
             new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
             color: Color(0xff5CE6B8),
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(17),
             child: Text(
               "Finalizar",
               style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 16
               ),
             ),
             onPressed: (){
               Navigator.push(
                   context,
                   MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder: (context) => Tela_Principal()
                   )
               );
             }
         ),
       )
     ],
   ),
  )
);
```

Comment: Opa, tudo bom? Edita a sua pergunta e adiciona o código referente ao seu problema, ao invés de um print... Assim podemos te ajudar de uma forma mais fácil. Se quiser pode editar [Clicando aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/494839/edit)

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285620/alinhamento-radio-com-imagem

Comment: Uma dica pra te ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo é que envolva seus componentes em um container e coloque cores de fundo nesse container. Assim vc consegue visualizar melhor os espaçamentos e qual parte não está no local que deseja permitindo o ajuste no local certo.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu deseja é colocar ao lado, imagino que a ideia é ter uma Linha com 2 componentes. No seu código existe apenas a coluna colocando um abaixo do outro. Faça uma alteração e insira o Widget `Row` com 2 childrens, um pra bandeira e outro pro radio.

Exemplo:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Row(children: [
      //item1, 
      //item2
    ]),
    Row(childrens: [
      //item1, 
      //item2
    ]),
    Row(childrens: [
      //item1, 
      //item2
    ]),
  ]
)
```

No seu código seria algo assim pra cada iten da sua coluna:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Image.asset("Imagens/Coreano.jpg", width: 500, height: 50),
    Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 0),
        child: RadioListTile(
          title: Text("Coreano"),
          activeColor: Color(0xff5CE6B8),
          value: "coreano",
          groupValue: _escolhaUsuario,
          onChanged: (String escolha) {
            setState(() {
              _escolhaUsuario = escolha;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Quando eu faço isso a minha tela fica toda branca